# In a popup, how do I add a file to the ajax submit and stay in the popup for the results of the backend?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, coldfusion

I found setting the title a bit awkward, it's complicated to exaplain in 1 sentence.. Some of our pages use popups where the user can fill in fields and then send. This is based on some Kallyas stuff and works fine with just text fields. After submitting, user staus on the same page, the form stays open and in it the message appears that the form has been sent (or not). There is also recaptcha handling in it.
Now I need to give the possibility to upload a file and this is where I am stuck. There is a .js file that does the handling. It picks up the form and does a ajax submit. I can see the form field of my input type="file" here, but with a fakepath/empty. If, in this javascript  I try to append the file to the form I can submit, but the the backend says the form field is not there.
First, let me share the code.

The form :

```
<!-- Application form pop-up element content -->
<div id="application_panel" class="mfp-hide contact-popup">
    <div class="contact-popup-panel">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <!-- Application form pop-up element -->
                    <div class="applicationForm pop-up-form" style="padding:50px;">
                        <!-- Title -->
                        <div id="jatitlewrapper">
                            <h3 class="m_title m_title_ext text-custom contact-popup-title c_title">
                                Some title   
                            </h3>
                            <h4 class="tbk__subtitle fw-thin dark">
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <form id="appform" action="#request.projectname#/scripts/ajax/save/processform.cfm" method="post" class="contact_form row mt-40" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div id="jafldwrapper">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 kl-fancy-form">
                                    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="cf_firstname-pop-up" class="form-control" placeholder="Vul hier je voornaam in" value="" tabindex="1" required>
                                    <label class="control-label">
                                        VOORNAAM
                                    </label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-6 kl-fancy-form">
                                    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="cf_lastname-pop-up" class="form-control" placeholder="Type je achternaam in" value="" tabindex="1" required>
                                    <label class="control-label">
                                        ACHTERNAAM
                                    </label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-12 kl-fancy-form">
                                    <input type="text" name="place" id="cf_place-pop-up" class="form-control" placeholder="Voeg een onderwerp toe" value="" tabindex="1" required maxlength="78">
                                    <label class="control-label">
                                        WOONPLAATS
                                    </label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <label class="label_upl">
                                        UPLOAD FILE
                                    </label>
                                    <input id="resume" style="padding-bottom:15px;" type="file" name="resume" id="cf_subject-pop-up" class="" placeholder="" value="" tabindex="1">
                                </div>
                                <cfif Application.isProductionURL>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-left:15px;">
                                        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="somesitekey"></div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <!-- Contact form send button -->
                                        <button id="submitbtn" class="btn btn-fullcolor" type="submit" onClick="$('.g-recaptcha-response').attr('name','g_recaptcha_response');">
                                            Send
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                <cfelse>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <!-- Contact form send button -->
                                        <button id="submitbtn" class="btn btn-fullcolor" type="submit">
                                            Send
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </cfif>
                                <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:right;">
                                    <button class="btn btn-fullcolor" type="button" onClick="closePopup();">
                                        Cancel
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="fjobuuid" id="fjobuuid" value="">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!--/ Application form pop-up element -->
                </div>
                <!--/ col-md-12 col-sm-12 -->
            </div>
            <!--/ .row -->
        </div>
        <!--/ .container -->
    </div>
    <!--/ .contact-popup-panel -->
    <button title="Sluiten (Esc)" type="button" class="mfp-close">×</button>
</div>
<!--/ Application form pop-up element content -->
```

Some javascript for the popup to show :

```
window.onload = function() {
    $('.abutton').magnificPopup({
        closeBtnInside: true,
        type: 'inline',
        preloader: false
    });
}
```

The standard js that handles the sumbit and works with all text fields on the form :

```
if(typeof($('.applicationForm form, .applicationForm.pop-up-form form, .contact_form form')) != 'undefined') {
    $.each($('.applicationForm form, .applicationForm.pop-up-form form, .contact_form form'), function(index, el) {
        var cform = $(el),
            cResponse = $('<div class="cf_response col-sm-12"></div>');
        cform.prepend(cResponse);
        cform.h5Validate();

        cform.submit(function(e) {
            $('#g-recaptcha-response').attr('name','g_recaptcha_response');

            e.preventDefault();
            if(cform.h5Validate('allValid')) {
                cResponse.hide();
                $.post(
                    $(this).attr('action'),
                    cform.serialize(),
                    function(data){
                        console.log(data);

                        cResponse.html(data).fadeIn('fast');
                        if(data.match('success') != null) {
                            cform.get(0).reset();
                        }
                    }
                ); // end post
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
}
```

The backend does some handling of the fields and then produces a message, which is then visible in the popup :

```
    <cfoutput><div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert"><p>Message sent, thank you</p></div></cfoutput>
```

or a message with class alert-danger if something went wrong.

Now I tried adding the file field 'resume' to the form by adding a cform.append, right after the cform.submit :

```
var files = $("#resume")[0].files;
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    cform.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
}
```

It does loop and seems to append the file.
But the backend says form.resume is not there.

I tried writing my own submit :

```
$("#submitbtn").on("click", function(e) {

    var form = $("#appform");
    var params = form.serializeArray();
    var files = $("#resume")[0].files;
    var formData = new FormData();
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        formData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
    }
    $(params).each(function (index, element) {
        formData.append(element.name, element.value);
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(form).prop("action"),
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        error   : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);}
        ,
        success : function(data){
            console.log(data);  
        }       
    });
})
```

Then the backend has all fields needed, including the actual file. But then I don't know how to integrate staying on the same url with the popup still in place and the message from the backend in the right place.

Then I tried changing the button type from sumbit to button, but then it won't let me send the file with the ajax call.

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'proctname//scripts/ajax/save/processform.cfm',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                error   : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);}
                ,
                success : function(data){
                    var obj = $.parseJSON( data );
                    console.log(data);  
                }       
            });
```

Giving form field 'resume' is undefined. Apparently it needs to be a form submit.

Can I add the file field 'resume' to the standard code after the cform.submit, keep page and popup open, have the message handling etetc and if so, how?

Comment: Not sure if I understand it right, but you may just need to stop the default form process propagation caused by pressing the submit button. You should do this by adding the event.PreventDefault() to your onclick handler to prevent the form also being HTML-submitted, or just not use a form: when you create ajax requests, a form is not necessarily needed. You could wrap your inputs with <div id="form"> instead, and prevent form submit propagation  that way. But of course all depends on your app.

Comment: @AndreasRu I added e.preventdefault(), but it then comes back with an error (although in the success handler but the backend procesForm.cfm is not executed) : 'invalid variable name declaration [request.------WebKitFormBoundarylbafoiDUEWEvCKJG
Content-Disposition: form-data; name]' Then I have processData: false, contenttype:false. Played around with those, it only works with contentType: 'multipart/form-data' but then my form.resume file field is being skipped. Starting to think I need 2 processes; 1st upload the file, then the submit of the (rest) of the form.

Comment: did you also  try it with the common event.preventDefault()?

Comment: Yes, that did not work out. But I think it is a ColdFusion issue rather than jquery/ajax issue. I now solved the issue by first submitting only the text fields and then only the file and that works out well. Thank you for trying to help.